# Dose not creating rar file with command prompt in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I am writing the following command on command prompt

```
C:/>"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a c:\test.rar c:\test
```

This is giving the following message

Can not create C:\test.rar

and

Access is denied

Comment: By default, UAC prevents you from writing to the root level of a drive in Windows 7. Change your path, and ask the real question on a more appropriate site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be you do not have admin right on "C" drive, thus it happens

So please change it to another drive like below and then try: -

eg.: -

```
C:/>rar a D:\test.rar D:\test
```

Comment: It may just be the root directory, try writing to "C:\Users\UserName\Documents" if you don't have another drive available